# Performance of calculations with mixed built-in Python numeric types and Numpy scalar numeric data types

Tags: python, numpy

I was writing a parser for some data stored in large text files (1Gb+)

Output was a numpy array of complex numbers, so naturally I used statements like

```
vals[...] = real_part + 1j*imag_part
```

where `real_part` and `imag_part` were obtained from `numpy.fromstring(...)`

I noticed that if I simply replace `vals[...] = real_part + 1j*imag_part` with

```
vals[...] = 1j*imag_part + real_part
```

I get almost x2 performance boost, which can be significant for large datasets.

I did some testing and obtained confusing results:

Code:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

a = np.float64(1.0)
print('type of 1j*a+a is',type(1j*a+a))
print('type of a+1j*a is',type(a+1j*a))
print('type of a+a*1j is',type(a+a*1j))

setup_line = 'import numpy as np; b = np.zeros(1,dtype=complex)'
N = 1000000
t1 = timeit.timeit("a=np.fromstring('1.1 2.2',sep=' ',dtype=float); b[0]=1j*a[1]+a[0]", setup=setup_line, number=N)
t2 = timeit.timeit("a=np.fromstring('1.1 2.2',sep=' ',dtype=float); b[0]=a[0]+1j*a[1]", setup=setup_line, number=N)
t3 = timeit.timeit("a=np.fromstring('1.1 2.2',sep=' ',dtype=float); b[0]=a[0]+a[1]*1j", setup=setup_line, number=N)

print(f't2/t1 = {t2/t1}')
print(f't3/t1 = {t3/t1}')

print(f'type of 1.0*a is {type(1.0*a)}')
print(f'type of 1.0.__mul__(a) is {type((1.0).__mul__(a))}')
print(f'type of a.__rmul__(1.0) is {type(a.__rmul__(1.0))}')
print(f'type of a*1.0 is {type(a*1.0)}')


print(f'type of 1j*a is {type(1j*a)}')
print(f'type of a*1j is {type(a*1j)}')
```

Output:

```
type of 1j*a+a is <class 'complex'>
type of a+1j*a is <class 'numpy.complex128'>
type of a+a*1j is <class 'numpy.complex128'>
t2/t1 = 2.720535618997823
t3/t1 = 3.9634173211365487
type of 1.0*a is <class 'numpy.float64'>
type of 1.0.__mul__(a) is <class 'float'>
type of a.__rmul__(1.0) is <class 'numpy.float64'>
type of a*1.0 is <class 'numpy.float64'>
type of 1j*a is <class 'complex'>
type of a*1j is <class 'numpy.complex128'>
```

So performance is better in the first case because all calculations are executed in Python built-in `complex` class. Performance boost is also close to practical case with line-by-line parsing.

What's more confusing is why type of `1.0*a` is not equal to `(1.0).__mul__(a)` but equal to `a.__rmul__(1.0)`? Is it how it's supposed to be?

What's the difference between `1.0*a` and `1j*a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @hpaulj. There you can see that the difference goes away for larger amounts of data.

For

```
a = np.random.random(size=10**7)
%timeit 1j*a+a
%timeit a+1j*a
%timeit a+a*1j
```

I get

```
152 ms ± 7.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
158 ms ± 2.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
151 ms ± 2.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

i.e. no significant difference. Did you have a difference on your actual data or was it just in a 1 value try case?

### To answer your comment: Does it matter performance wise if I am using numpy functions line by line or on on a large amount at once?

Unfortunately this is one of the most important things using numpy. You really want to avoid using loops and applying numpy functions one by one but rather want to work with arrays and let numpy handle everything at once.

My suggestion is to use `pandas` for this task. My test shows that it is ~3 times faster than plane python. My setup

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

n = 10**7
test_string = "\n".join(map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}, {x[1]}", zip(np.random.random((n)),np.random.random((n)))))
```

Pure python taking ~11.6 seconds ± 64.9 ms:

```
%%timeit
arr = np.empty(n,dtype='complex')
for i,line in enumerate(test_string.split('\n')):
    x,y = line.split(', ')
    arr[i] = float(x)+1j*float(y)
```

Pandas taking ~3.6 seconds ± 43.6 ms:

```
%%timeit
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(test_string),names=['1', 'j'])
out = df['1']+1j*df['j'].to_numpy()
```

Comment: Large amount of data is not the case. In practical case I go line-by-line over chunk of text data, extract from each line 2 float values (real and imag parts of complex number), make a complex number out of them and put it into Numpy array. Though input data have periodic structure, none of Numpy built-in functions seems to be able to deal with it. Regular expressions is slow and so I'm using line-by-line approach (with multiprocessing, but that's not relevant).

Comment: Second part of the question was not about equivalency of resultant values, but of their types. `1j*a` is `<class 'complex'>` as it can be expected, but `1.0*a` is `<class 'numpy.float64'>` and not `<class 'float'>`. Why, what's the difference?

Comment: @8xb2vsda62 Oh then I can't answer your 2nd question. That's weird. I did write something on your first comment though.

Comment: @8xb2vsda62 You're welcome. Do you consider your question answered then?

Comment: well, the question what's going on with `complex` when multiplied by `numpy.float64` still remains.

Comment: I think you should ask that separately if you actually want to know.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the 'raw' times will tell us more than the ratios:

```
In [182]: timeit 1j*a+a
209 ns ± 12.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [183]: timeit a+1j*a
5.26 µs ± 11.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [184]: timeit a+a*1j
10 µs ± 9.28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

With a single value calculation like this, function calls and conversion to/from numpy can dominate the times.  We aren't seeing the 'pure' calculation times.  For that we need to work with larger arrays.

It's well known, for example, that `math.sin` is better than `np.sin` on a single value.  The `np.sin` is faster with 100's of values.  I suspect something like this is going on here, but don't have time now to explore it.

Comment: I changed example code so now it's as close to practical case as I can make it. Still  `1j*a+a` is two times better than other variants and it really can make a difference.